# Create Registry in both Wow6432Node and normal hive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, add-in

So I created an MSI for Outlook Addin using Visual Sudio 2010 adding registry key as:

[image: Reg Hive]

and ran it and it puts the registry keys in the `Wow6432Node` although both Office and Windows is x64.

I run windows 7 and Office 2010 x64.

Then I exported myAddin registry hive and edited it so it pointed to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins`. Opened Outlook and guess what....the addin shows up.

Next question, how do I add the registry keys to both normal and `Wow6432Node` hive in Visual Studio?

This is a followup form this question: [Outlook COM addin installed but not loading in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049588/outlook-com-addin-installed-but-not-loading-in-outlook)

Comment: Why do you want to put it into both hives? Is your goal to support both x64 Office and x86 Office with your addin? Technically - you just need it to appear in one hive since you can't have 2 versions of office installed - right?

Comment: Hi SilverNinja. I tried adding it just on x64 hive which was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins but once hte addin is installed the entries automatically go to Wow6432Node hive and the addin does not show up in Outlook COMAddin. But when I manually add the the keys to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddin then the addin loads up when Outlook is launched with no problem.

Comment: Perhaps slightly pedantic but Wow6432Node is not a registry "hive", it's just a registry key. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For x64 Office, [make sure you assign the proper **TargetPlatform**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7a85k9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (*under VS Setup Project Properties*) so that the installer knows which registry location to assign. The default `TargetPlatform` is x86 which will place your registry hives into `Wow6432Node` on a x64 OS host.

#### VS Setup Project (x64 Office)

> TargetPlatform = x64

#### VS Setup Project (x86 Office)

> TargetPlatform = x86

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja. I didnt realise that setting. So I have changed the TargetPlatform to x64, compiled and installed the .msi. It placed the files in Program Files instead of Program Files (x86) which is normal and placed the registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddin as expected. However when i launch Outlook it still doesnt show up the Addin.

Comment: @James - What's the platform target you use when you build your VSTO project (*Any CPU, x86, etc.*)?

Comment: When building the VSTO, it is set to Release and Any CPU. I dont see anything about the platform.

Comment: I think you can only get the platform option on VS Pro, not VS Express, I presume you are using the latter?

Comment: **Any CPU** includes both x86 and x64 compatible assemblies. I would figure out what changed since it used to work when you manually created the key. I'm guessing the value of your manifest may be incorrect. What is the value of the **Manifest key**?

Comment: Is this what you mean? <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime" version="4.0.30319.0" />

Comment: The manifest key is created in the registry by your installer. The installed value should be something like `file:///C:/Program Files/ThisIsMyAddIn/ThisIsMyAddin.vsto|vstolocal`. If this value is invalid - the VSTO runtime will not load your addin properly. Sometimes this also referred to as [VSTO Fastpath](http://ericphan.info/blog/2011/4/11/vsto-addins-break-after-visual-studio-2010-sp1-install-cant.html)

Comment: Manifest=C:\Program Files\MyOutlookAddin\OutlookAddin\OutlookAddIn.vsto|vstolocal

Comment: @James Change the value to use the **URI schema** format...`file:///[TARGETDIR]OutlookAddIn.vsto|vstolocal` in your VS Setup Project.

Comment: Sorry SilverNinja. That was from Regedit. In VS, it is as [TARGETDIR].

Comment: @James You need to add the prefix `file:///`