# Will a 32bit VSTO 4 Excel 2007 Addin work on 64bit Windows Server 2003 with Excel 2007 32bit?

Tags: .net, vsto, excel-2007, ms-office, excel-addins

We have a VSTO 4 32bit Excel Add-in which works fine on Windows XP (and Server 2003) 32bit. We are planning to upgrade our servers to Windows 2003 64bit OS and Excel 2007 32bit. My question is whether our existing Excel Add-in will still work.

Also is the VSTO 4 runtime 64bit only meant for 64bit Office?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So long as you keep the Office version **target platform** the same it will work just fine. If you change from Office x86 to Office x64 then you would need to build an installer that targets x64 instead of the default x86. Changing the OS platform won't cause you any issues.

See [related SO post regarding **TargetPlatform**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071907/175679).

The VSTO 4 x64 runtime is only meant to be used with Office x64.